# Customize Madison Island(RWD) to use it for production

Tags: magento-1.9, rwd-theme

First of all I'd like to say that I'm new to Magento so be I may ask something that might not be wise!

I've been reading and following tutorials about Magento for two weeks now. Here are some of my questions that are specific, so please give me tips on how to go ahead.

- Can I use the base theme of 1.9.2.1 RWD Madison Island for my production site and customize it?
- I've followed [this documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce19-ee114/RWD_dev-guide.html) , but I still can't figure out if I can edit the SASS files because of this notation on them.

***// DISCLAIMER
//
// Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
// versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
// needs please refer to magento for more information.***

- So how to go further with customizing RWD theme?

I just want to change some very basic things in this theme and use it for my production website. I don't want it to be more functional and beautiful than what this theme already is.

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this one:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce19-ee114/RWD_dev-guide.html

The guide has additional information you'll need to get started.

Comment: Thanks @AdarshKhatri, I've read the article http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce19-ee114/RWD_dev-guide.html does it mean that I can make my own theme based on RWD and just change it a little and can use it as production?

Comment: That's what you have to do.